# Symfony : Need custom action in generator.yml pointing to different module

Tags: symfony1

How can I add custom action in generator.yml that point to an action in different module than current. In other words, I am expecting something like below.

```
  // snippet from apps/backend/modules/users/config/generator.yml
  edit:
    title:         User details
    display:       [city, state, country, zip, phone, sms, email]
    actions:
      _save: { label: Save }
      _listProfile:     { label: List Profiles, action: listProfiles, module: profile }
```

Note that **listProfiles** action is part of **profile** module where the generator.yml belong to **users** module. The above does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. But you should be able to create a custom action and [forward or redirect to the other action](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_skipping_to_another_action) inside this action.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I created a new action in same module and then forward it to the required module.